# Socket creation speed huge difference Python3.7/Python2.7

Tags: python, sockets, time

I'm trying to create a socket, then connect to the same server until I can't make any connection from my PC and I face a problem : my program is WAY faster with Python 2.7 than with Python 3.7.

Here a minimal example:

```
# client.py

import time
import socket

begin = time.time()
socket_list = []

while True:
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(1)
        s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 65432))
        socket_list.append(s)
    except:
        print(len(socket_list))
        print(time.time() - begin)
        for sock in socket_list:
            sock.close()
        break

# server.py

import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 65432

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen()
while True:
    s.accept()
```

Ouput with Python 3.7 client side and Python 3.7 server side:

```
16298
32.764869928359985
```

Ouput with Python 2.7 client side and Python 3.7 server side:

```
16297
1.86599993706
```

**OS:** Windows 10

**Server:**

<s>Gitlab server running in my local network, on a different computer.</s>

The above-mentionned server.

**Note:** Please, do not test this other than locally.

**Edit:** Added the server part, just to be sure this is not the problem

Comment: I've tested on my PC(Windows 7, Anaconda distro) and don't see any considerable performance difference in either envs. For Python 3.7, I get `16284
46.24759030342102` and for Python 2.7, I get `16283
48.2610001564`. I tested this with a Flask server running locally on 127.0.0.1, port 5000.

Comment: @amanb Ok thanks for your reply. My test was done with a Gitlab server on a different computer, in a local network. I really do not see where the problem could come from.

Comment: Removing the line `s.settimeout(1)` solved the problem, I now have similar performance with Python 2.7 and Python 3. Why, I don't know.